# .htaccess добавление текста к ссылке

Tags: php, .htaccess

Есть ссылка вида `www.example.com` и `www.example.com/en/`
как сделать так , чтобы , например если пользователь введет `www.example.com/about` он перенаправлял на `www.example.com/en/about` , и вне зависимости от вводимого пользователем значения , он добавлял к ссылке `/en/` + `ввод пользователя`.

вот содержимое .htaccess корня www.example.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/robots.txt
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^.*$ /en/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

Только так он не добавляет к ссылке ввод , а просто редиректит любое введенное значение на example.com/en/

```
!! Не относится к вопросу
```

(добавляю код который искал = открывает ссылки без расширения .php кому понадобится )

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ $0.php [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ([^\s]*)\.php(\?[^\s]*)?
RewriteRule (.*) %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^.*$ /en/$1 [NC,R=301,L]` может так?

Comment: минуту , проверю

Comment: делает тоже что и у меня в комментарии , перенаправляет любой ввод на www.example.com/en/

Comment: `RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [NC,R=301,L]`

Comment: Alex спасибо , ваш способ рабочий , плюсую.

Comment: @S1lllver Вы имеете ввиду комментарий выше? ответ опубликован не наш )

Comment: не совсем понял если честно) но и ответ и комментарий оба работают , сейчас ищу способ открывать страницы без расширения .php

Comment: @S1lllver ответ не я опубликовал (не тот Alex, который комментарий с ответом написал), но дублировать ответ не хочу, примите ответ =)

Comment: а все понял , я оба плюсанул))

Comment: и кстати если кому понадобится , открывать страницы без расширения .php , код добавляю наверх

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

или

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ <site>/en/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```